# How can I avoid the user to add a repeated int value to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, repeat

First of all, I'm trying to do this using only simple conditions since I don't know how to use Hashmaps.

Ok, here is what I got so far, but I got stuck. Do you guys know a way in which I can compare an int to all the ints in an array?

```
public void rep() throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the value for the position # " + (1+i) + " of the array.");
        int lol = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());


        if(!Arrays.Equals(arr[i], lol))
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some high-level description about what your code is trying to do.

Comment: The user will enter the size of the array, and then enter the n int elements. But it should prevent repetition.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
boolean repeat = false;
for(int j=0; j<i; j++ )
{
    if(arr[j] == lol)
    {
       repeat = true;
       break;
    }

} 
if(!repeat)
     arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following method

```
for(i=0;i<intArray.length;i++){
if(intValue==intArray[i])
{ //write codes for if   }
else{
// write codes for else  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(arr).contains(lol)
```

what the above function is doing it coverts the array to list and the apply contains method to check if element is present